# How to access a vector array?

Tags: c++, vector

```
std::vector<int> example[1024];
```

How can I access all 1024 "examples" and their vector elements?

When I try `example[0]` it is the same like `example.at(0)` and I access the the first element in a vector...

I want to do the same as with variables: 
int variable[1024]; ... but instead of an integer there is a vector...

Comment: First figure out what an array is. Once you understand that, it will be clear what `example[0]` means.

Comment: its not clear what you want to accomplish

Comment: `example.at(0)` is illegal, `example[0]` gives you the first vector. This is the same as `int variable[1024];` except with vectors instead of ints.

Comment: Keep in mind that with this declaration alone you only have a static, C-style array of 1024 empty vectors of int `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really clear what do you want to accomplish, but generally std::vector works pretty like classic C++ array.

And all the elements go one after another in memory, so you can do this for example

```
  std::vector<int> test(1024);
  test[0] = 1;
  test[1] = 4;
  test[2] = 8;

  int* first = &test[0];
  std::cout << "First is " << *first << std::endl;
  int* second = first + 1;
  std::cout << "Second is " << *second << std::endl;
```

Comment: vector::data is a better way, but the result is the same http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/